# INNER JOIN after a GROUP BY statement with COUNT Function

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables called `purchase` and `costs`.

`Purchase` contains my purchase data like this:

| id | date | source_name | purchase_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014-02-21 | source A | 1000 |
| 2 | 2014-02-30 | source B | 250 |
| 3 | 2014-03-14 | source B | 150 |
| N | ... | ... | ... |

`Costs` contains the cost base on number of purchase. Note: if needed you can change this table definition

| source_name | from_purchase | fee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| source A | 1 | 1.5 |
| source A | 11 | 1.4 |
| source A | 21 | 1.3 |
| source B | 1 | 1.0 |
| source B | 11 | 0.9 |
| source B | 21 | 0.8 |

I am trying to write a `SELECT` statement which will return the results like this:

| month   | source_name | transaction_count | fee      | total_fees |
| ------- | --------- | ----------------- | --------- | ---------- |
| 2014-02 | Source A   | 5                 | 1.5       | 7.5        |
| 2014-02 | Source B    | 15                | 0.9       | 13.5
...

how do I create a join statement and compare the transaction count with the from_purchase column?

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Please only tag the **single** rdbms you are using. I removed the conflicting tags.

Comment: I don't understand the data model. We see from the transactions table that transaction #1 is a Bank A transaction. From the fees table, however, we see that the transaction #1 involves Bank A and Bank B somehow. So, do we count the transaction for Bank A only or for both banks?

Comment: And what is `fee` vs. `total_fees` in your results? You are showing one result row per month and bank. So is `fee` the total fee for the month and bank? If not, what else is it? And if this is the total fee for the month and bank, then what is `total_fee`? Maybe you should better show us a complete sample where the result matches the data in the tables shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try a derived table with a join.

```sql
SELECT t.*, t.transaction_count * f.fee as [total_fees]
FROM ( 
    SELECT to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') AS month, transactions.bank_name, 
    COUNT(transfer_amounts) as transaction_count
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM'), transactions.bank_name
    ) t
INNER JOIN FEES f
ON f.bank_name = t.bank_name
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is

```sql
WITH fees_expanded AS (
  SELECT *, COALESCE(LEAD(from_transaction) OVER w - 1, 9999999) AS to_transaction
    FROM fees
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY bank_name ORDER BY from_transaction)
)
SELECT t.*, f.fee, t.transaction_count * f.fee AS total_fees 
  FROM transactions t
  JOIN fees_expanded f
    ON t.bank_name = f.bank_name
   AND t.transaction_count BETWEEN f.from_transaction AND f.to_transaction;
```

[db<>fiddle-Postgres 14](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d297268ae9087925b9213b7a5091cbf7)

[image]